How to send large data to the renderer process with low latency in electron?
I'm working on a video-related project where I've disabled nodeIntegration and enabled contextIsolation for security reasons. My task involves processing business logic in the utility process and then sending YUV data to the renderer process for rendering using VideoFrame and canvas. However, I've encountered a significant issue when dealing with 6K resolution videos. After decoding, the YUV data is extremely large, and the time it takes to send this data to the renderer process is prohibitively long. As a result, I'm unable to achieve the desired frame rate of 30 frames per second. My system is equipped with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz.
Here is the code I use to measure the time:
setInterval(()=> {
  const beforeAlloc = performance.now()
  const data = new Uint8Array(4000_0000)  // large array
  // const data = new Uint8Array(4000)
  const afterAlloc = performance.now()

  const beforeSend = performance.now()
  port.postMessage(data) // the port is MessageChannelMain.port
  const afterSend = performance.now()

  const now = performance.now()
  // alloc's time was almost negligible, while postMessage took more than 90% of the time
  console.log(`alloc: ${parseInt(afterAlloc - beforeAlloc)}, send: ${parseInt(afterSend - beforeSend)}, time since last: ${parseInt(now - lastTime)}`)
  lastTime = now
}, 1000 / 30)

Output when sending large data:
alloc: 0, send: 77, time since last: 77
alloc: 3, send: 76, time since last: 80
alloc: 3, send: 82, time since last: 85
alloc: 0, send: 84, time since last: 85
alloc: 3, send: 78, time since last: 82
alloc: 3, send: 95, time since last: 99
...

Output when sending small data:
alloc: 0, send: 0, time since last: 46
alloc: 0, send: 0, time since last: 46
alloc: 0, send: 0, time since last: 46
alloc: 0, send: 0, time since last: 48
alloc: 0, send: 0, time since last: 46
alloc: 0, send: 0, time since last: 46
...

To avoid blocking the main process, I've opted to handle this logic in a utility process and communicate using MessageChannelMain, but I've found that this approach is not very efficient either. The most efficient solution I can think of is to enable nodeIntegration and disable contextIsolation, allowing the renderer process to directly access and render the YUV data. However, I would prefer not to do this unless absolutely necessary. So, I'm wondering if there are any other methods for efficiently transferring large amounts of data between processes? Additionally, I'm not sure if my approach is flawed. I need to display the frames being processed in real time. Are there any other solutions available?
Here is the Github repository address.
Here is the complete code screenshot.
Lastly, my English is not very good, so I'm not sure if I've made my point clear. Please forgive any misunderstandings. I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions. Thank you in advance for your help.

"I need to display the frames being processed in real time"  What does "processed" mean exactly in your question (eg: what happens to the input frame's pixels)? It's possible the data does not need to be 6K and should be resized even before the processing starts (maybe try resizing into 720p) and let the processing and playback happen by using the smaller version.

Hello, sorry for the confusion. The utility process is doing "streaming => decoding => processing => encoding => streaming". I need to capture YUV data during "decoding" and render it using canvas. Since it's a 6K video, the YUV data is huge. The problem is high latency when sending YUV data to the renderer process. You are right, a 1080P screen might not need 6K YUV data. Should I convert it to 1080P YUV before sending it to the renderer, right?
@VC.One
